# Iterating over a list of lists with a conditional formulas in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

I have three input lists as follows:

```
fill_rgn_pts = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]]
fill_rgn = [[region1],[region2],[region3],[region4]]
rooms = [[room1],[room2],[room3],[room4],[room5],[room6]]
```

I am trying to pair fill_rgn and rooms based on whether all fill_rgn_pts are contained within the room. Here's what I have tried so far:

```
valid_rooms, valid_fill_rgn, invalid_rooms = [], [], []

for i in rooms:
    for list, region in zip(fill_rgn_pts, fill_rgn):
        if all(i.IsPointInRoom(j) == True for j in list):
            valid_rooms.append(i)
            valid_fill_rgn.append(region)
        else:
            invalid_rooms.append(i)
OUT = valid_fill_rgn, valid_rooms, invalid_rooms
```

What I am getting back from this are three lists:

```
valid_fill_rgn = [[region1],[region2],[region3],[region4]]
valid_rooms = [[room1],[room2],[room3],[room4]]
invalid_rooms = [[room1],[room1],[room1],[room2],[room2],[room2],[room3],[room3],[room3],[room4],[room4],[room4],[room4],[room5],[room5],[room5],[room6],[room6],[room6],[room6]]
```

The first two lists look exactly how I want them since they paired up a region and room how I expected it. The third list however returns too many items. I am getting three extra values for each room, which makes me think that I am iterating over something that I shouldn't. Ideas?

Comment: `list` is a poor choice for a variable as it shadows the built-in `list()`.

Comment: good point, rookie mistake i will correct that.

Comment: What are `regionX` and `roomX`? Custom objects?

Comment: yes, room is a custom object so is region. IsPointInRoom is a class that checks if a point is contained in a room (it's from Revit API a 3D modeling software). Those are working well. I think i have a list comprehension issue here.

Comment: Minor nitpick, you dont need == True there

Comment: True that but it makes it clear for me as a new Python user as to what I am checking for/against. Thank you for the suggestion though

Comment: @Bachmann - Unless something in `IsPointInRoom` could return something true-ish that's not actually `True` at some point that he's accounting for.  Otherwise, I agree.

Comment: IsPointInRoom will always return either True or False so I probably dont need that, then again I am newbie so I like the clarity.

Comment: Can a room be in more than one region?  I think you might benefit from a `break` statement after adding a room to the valid or invalid lists.

Comment: @konrad I think you are getting the minus votes because it is generally better to provide fully independent code that anyone looking at your question can run. Luckily guy below you has you an answer :-)

Comment: @Bachmann I see. Well this is not really something that you can run outside of Revit application so I have to improvise a little bit. Yes, his tip about the sets is a good one, i am just not sure how to implement it. I will keep trying. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not compute invalid rooms last?

After finding valid rooms

```
fill_rgn_pts = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]]
fill_rgn = [[region1],[region2],[region3],[region4]]
rooms = [[room1],[room2],[room3],[room4],[room5],[room6]]

for i in rooms:
    for list, region in zip(fill_rgn_pts, fill_rgn):
        if all(i.IsPointInRoom(j) == True for j in list):
            valid_rooms.append(i)
            valid_fill_rgn.append(region)

invalid_rooms = [room for room in rooms if room not in valid_rooms]
OUT = valid_fill_rgn, valid_rooms, invalid_rooms
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can fix this by changing `invalid_rooms` and `valid_rooms` to a *`set`*, which will not allow duplicates.

Your loop repeats the addition for each point/range pair, which is why you keep getting duplicates in your `valid_rooms` and `invalid_rooms` list. Once a room is marked as valid or invalid, you don't need to add it again.

Further, you seem to have a list with just one item, `[room1]`, it would be better just to have the individual rooms:

```
rooms = [room1,room2,room3,room4,room5,room6]
```

Comment: valid_rooms, valid_fill_rgn, invalid_rooms = set(), [], set()

for i in rooms:
 for lst, region in zip(fill_rgn_pts, fill_rgn):
  if all(i.IsPointInRoom(j) == True for j in lst):
   valid_rooms.add(i)
   valid_fill_rgn.append(region)
  else:
   invalid_rooms.add(i)
#Assign your output to the OUT variable
OUT = valid_fill_rgn, valid_rooms, invalid_rooms

Comment: so i changed the valid_rooms and invalid_rooms to be set() instead of [] and then instead of appending i used add() but i am still getting all of the same rooms in the invalid_rooms as were already assigned to valid_rooms.

Comment: Now you have a different problem :)

Comment: so i added invalid_rooms.difference_update(valid_rooms) to get rid of duplicates. Now I am getting what I wanted...is that bad coding? I want to learn the proper way.

Comment: No, its not bad coding - why would you think that?